# Is it possible with CSS to target letters within a paragraph without span?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add an effect to my letters, but I don't want to add a bunch of span tags all over the place. Is it possible to target a specific letter within a line of text with CSS?

I know there is `:first-child, :first-of-type, :only-child, :last-child, :last-of-type, :only-of-type ,:nth-child, :nth-of-type ,:nth-last-child` and `:nth-last-of-type` I believe. But none of these help do what I want in any combination.

This is what I need to target letter by letter.
    `<p>Hello.</p>`

This is what I don't want. Nor **lettering.js**.

```
<p>
<span class"somefancyname">H</span>

<span class"somefancyname">e</span>

<span class"somefancyname">l</span>

<span class"somefancyname">l</span>

<span class"somefancyname">o</span>

<span class"somefancyname">.</span>
</p>
```

Lastly - Is it really **bad** to use that many `span` tags? I feel dirty if I use that many... not sure why really. Thanks in advanced! If someone can reword this to make sense - I feel I rambled a bit - thank you!

**Note:** I want to add different animations to the letters. Not just (1) place on the page - so that's why I'm concerned with multiple `span` tags. What animations? Some bouncing over here and some color changing over there and maybe some rotating over yonder. Is my only solution to use JS or just give in to the `span` tags?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in pure CSS. If you don't want to use spans, you may need some Javascript/jQuery.

Comment: How about a good ol' fashioned image?

Comment: @Yuriy That's what I'm afraid of. It's something pretty simple I don't feel the need to use JS - I thought if I asked here, maybe a CSS ninja would help.

Comment: The short answer to your question is, I'm afraid: 'no.'

Comment: @Tom - No, image would not do the same thing. But in another circumstance that would be okay ^-^.

Comment: Only the `:first-letter` is available via CSS.  A JS solution is going to insert the html tags for you, so there's not really a difference between a JS solution and what you've already got.

Comment: @cimmanon Yes - I tried that and it's great for the first letter - but not the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I know jquery can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
count = 0; limit = 10;
var refreshId = setInterval( function() {
if(count < limit) {

$( '.data tr:contains("blah")') .css( {"display":"none"} );
$( '.mainpart h2 a') .css( {"text-decoration":"underline" , "color":"#38c"} )

}
else {
clearInterval(refreshId);
}
}, 2000);
});
```